# MUI X Data Grid processRowUpdate gives wrong value from parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I have an MUI X Data Grid with `processRowUpdate` property. The function I have is

```
(newRow, oldRow) => {
  setLineItemRows((prevVals) =>
    prevVals.map((row) => {
      if (row.id === newRow.id) return { ...row, ...newRow };
      return row;
    })
  );
}
```

Here is my datagrid

```
<DataGrid
  sx={{
    height: 500,
    bgcolor: "white",
    fontSize: "0.92em",
    marginTop: "0.75rem",
  }}
  rows={lineItemRows}
  columns={lineItemsCols}
  disableRowSelectionOnClick
  editMode="row"
  rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
  onRowModesModelChange={handleRowModesModelChange}
  onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop}
  processRowUpdate={(newRow) => {
    console.log(lineItemRows);
    setEditItem(false);
    console.log(newRow, "new row enq");
    setLineItemRows((prevVals) =>
      prevVals.map((row) => {
        if (row.id === newRow.id) return { ...row, ...newRow };
        return row;
      })
    );
  }}
  onProcessRowUpdateError={(e) => {
    console.log(e);
  }}
  initialState={{
    pagination: {
      paginationModel: { pageSize: 25, page: 0 },
    },
  }}
  getRowClassName={({ row }) => {
    if (row.status === "Reject") return "datagrid-row-red";
  }}
/>
```

[image: This my log from processRowUpdate property. The error message os from onProcessRowUpdateError]

While logging the `newArray`, I get the second log result (from the image) and the first log message(array) is the array that i am passing to the `rows` property in my DataGrid. The third log message is generated from `onProcessRowUpdateError`

Here is the CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-marco-jp65t9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to accomplish? It would be helpful to share a minimal reproduction of your app, for example on CodeSandbox.

Comment: I have a datagrid who's rows are empty initially. So when i create a new record and save the details, I try to update the rows array using `processRowUpdate` property.

I have updated my question with my datagrid and with my log. Please do check it out. Hope you find a better idea of my problem now.

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can help you debug further. I'm not able to run your code to see what's going on otherwise. CodeSandbox is ideal—here's a sandbox with all the dependencies installed that you can fork and edit: https://codesandbox.io/s/hyks3m

Comment: I'm really sorry man, I for some reason forgot to include the CodeSandbox link while editing. Here you go
https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-marco-jp65t9?file=/src/App.js
Well, the newArray when logged in CodeSandbox gave the right result. But there is still the same error that shows up

Comment: Hey! @SamSycamore, got anything?